# Verb "render" and the following sentence

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I am currently reading the [Wiki about the War Of 1812](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_1812), just purely out of curiosity, and I encountered a passage. It says,

> At home, British faced mounting opposition to wartime taxation and demands to reopen trade with America. With the abdication of Napoleon, the blockade of France ended and Britain ceased impressment, **rendering the issue of the impressment of American sailors moot.** The British were then able to increase the strength of the blockade on the United States coast,

About the bold part, would that mean "The abdication of Napoleon (and consequent cease of British pressure) **put the issue of impressment American  sailors in a less significant position**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase is *to render something moot*. *Moot* has a couple of slightly different meanings, but here it means "irrelevant, of no consequence".

So the meaning of the phrase is a bit stronger than your paraphrase: something like "making the issue of impressment of American sailors irrelevant or unimportant".

I don't think the wording is at all clear, and it could probably do with some rewriting.

Comment: I can't really agree with your final sentence. The text as cited looks perfectly clear to me, and I don't think it's necessarily helpful to give learners the impression that anything they don't find easy to understand might simply be "badly written". English Wikipedia pages are primarily intended to be read by competent native Anglophones. And complex ideas often require complex language to be expressed - it's not really important how easily *non* natives can read the text.

Comment: +1 *Debate* over an issue is rendered moot if the issue itself ceases to be an issue.   The word **issue** is being used there on that Wiki page rather elliptically as a synonym for "strife/debate over impressment". (The practice had been unpopular at home in England and a provocation to the US when its citizens were impressed.)  The elliptical writing *is* a little unclear.  I don't think there's any harm done when a native speaker criticizes a bit of writing. A learner should have "hey, it's not me, it's the native speaker's use of the language" as a possible explanation for confusion.

Comment: I agree that this writing style is needlessly awkward. While grammatical, it's not something that should be promoted. Complex ideas *can* be expressed simply and succinctly. This is not an example of that.